# Traceroute to my IP address is slow while ping is fast

Tags: networking, perforce

When I have a connection to my network and I ping the IP address my machine is assigned, I get a fast response.  However, when I do a traceroute to my IP address, the command takes around a minute to complete even though it shows a response time of less than a millisecond.  Traceroute also shows no hops to my IP address.  I've ran into similar delays when trying to connect to services on the network like perforce.  Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Is the problem slow or failing reverse dns lookups? Does it help if you disable that? (`-n`? check your manual)

Comment: This does not belong on serverfault - maybe Superuser ?  (Flagged for moderator attention)

Comment: It could be failing DNS lookups.  Its probably also related to routing - possibly a firewall blocking certain types of ICMP traffic (as implied by the "Tracerouter also shows no hops to my IP address" bit)

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is clearly a misconfiguration of either the computer on which you are running the traceroute command or the network to which it is connected. The prime suspect is a misconfigured firewall.

There is no way the target of a traceroute could prevent the first few hops from being discovered, because the packets involved in discovering those hops won't even make it to the target system or back.

Here is a traceroute output, which I produced on a deliberately misconfigured client machine. Before running the traceroute command, I inserted `-A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP` into my firewall:

```
# traceroute -T -n 88.198.201.172
traceroute to 88.198.201.172 (88.198.201.172), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  88.198.201.172  52.141 ms  52.846 ms  51.885 ms
```

Comment: I didn't encounter exactly the same problem but I saw no connections being made to external IPs and traceroute was seriously slow.